# IOptionMonitor - emit change event

Tags: asp.net-core, appsettings

The asp.net core app has IOptions configured from two sources (a) appsetting.json and (b) database

I override the values from appsetting.json by values in database. Now I want to allow user to edit values on the fly for certain predefined settings (which are saved in database) e.g. enable stacktrace to debug some issue temporarily in production environment.

During initialization of application I override values in database, using `IconfigureOptions` as shown [here](https://tpodolak.com/blog/2017/02/26/asp-net-core-populating-ioptions-external-data-source/)

```
public class HostingOptionSetupService : IConfigureOptions<HostingOption>
{

    private readonly AppDbContext _dbContext;
    public AvailabilitySearchOptionsSetupService(AppDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this._dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public void Configure(AvailabilitySearchOptions options)
    {
        var json = ConvertToJsonString(_dbContext.AppSetting.ToList());
        JsonConvert.PopulateObject(options, json);
    }
}
```

But now, when user changes the values and it gets saved in database, how do I trigger rebind? How to use IOptionsMonitor on database changes??

Comment: The quickest way to get it to work is by using the IOptionsSnapshot<T> instead because it rebinds on every request. So each new request will get a new instance of IOptionsSnapshot<T> and use it for the scope of the request.

Comment: but then that would be everytime and not everytime the options value changes, its once in a while.. rather very rarely. Any other more performant option?

Comment: Blatantly put, no. By reading configuration from a database rather than a file, you have limited your possibilities.

Comment: @Dennis1679 its just about raising change event to IOptionMonitor on db save changes. Anyways, will find out a way and will put it as an answer

Comment: Ah, I thought you meant subscribing to changes in SQL database done outside of your application. I misunderstood. Good luck

Comment: I am using EF core, so its about raising the event on saveChanges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, I injected `IConfigureOptions` in the service which saves the changes to database. And then callled `configureOptions.Configure()` after `dbContext.SaveChanges` which reapplies the changes.